# No matter my argument, the function returns the else condition

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Please someone help me review my code, it keeps outputting not readable RNA no matter what argument I pass. Is something wrong with my if statement?

```
def rna_length(mrna):
    
    if (mrna[0:4] == 'AUG' ) and (mrna[-3:] in ('UAA','UGA','UAG')) :
        return len(mrna) - 6
    else:
        return "Not readable RNA "
        
        
print(rna_length('AUGFTUHUAA'))
```

Please help me.

Comment: `mrna[0:4]` is 4 characters, it can never be `== 'AUG'` unless `mrna` itself is `'AUG'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I now see my error. All of you on this platform are superstars!

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, you will see the error yourself:

```
def rna_length(mrna):
    print(mrna[0:4])
    print(mrna[-3:])
    if (mrna[0:4] == 'AUG') and (mrna[-3:] in ('UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG')):
        print(f"What is len(mrna) - {len(mrna)}")
        return len(mrna) - 6
    else:
        return "Not readable RNA "


print(rna_length('AUGFTUHUAA'))
```

E.g. `mrna[0:4] == 'AUG'` will always be `False` and thus the whole if will be `False`, because of the `And` condition.